# jQuery UI radio / controlgroup (in a dialog) works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this standard form, nothing fancy:

```
<form>
    <fieldset id="feedType">
        <legend class="ui-corner-top">Display Type</legend>
        <label for="mixed">Mixed</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="mixed" class="feedType" />

        <label for="photo">Photo</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="photo" class="feedType" />

        <label for="text">Text</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="text" class="feedType" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The corresponding code (full - module -function [here](https://pastebin.com/UnTjFYyu)) is inside the `open: function(event, ui) {})` part of a [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog):

```
$(this).find('#feedType').controlgroup();
```

And, well, **it works only once**. The dialog opens, the radio buttons are turned into jQuery UI buttons widgets ([jQuery UI controlgroup documentation](https://jqueryui.com/controlgroup)) and you can select any option, the selected button stays selected (and corresponding events are duly fired) and the others are thusly de-selected. This is the expected behaviour.

But when you close and re-open the dialog, be it on the same DOM object or on another one, while still technically working (the events are still fired, and the proper values set) **the buttons won't *visually* work anymore**. The button you click won't stay "clicked", they will all stay visually in their respective state (except for a slight/quick "active" click state).

#### Notes

In the same `open:` function I set the selected button like this:

```
$(this).find('input#' + oldType || 'mixed').prop("checked", true)
    .checkboxradio('refresh');
```

and it works fine, the right radio button is selected at opening time. Removing this won't solve the problem.

Now when I try to monitor what is going on:

```
$(this).find('.feedType').on("change", function(event){
    console.log("CHANGE EVENT!", $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This works fine, *each time*, too.

```
$(this).find('.feedType').checkboxradio({
    icon: false
});
```

Changes nothing to the behavior mentioned.

#### What I tried

```
$(this).find('.feedType').on("change", function(event){
    $dialog.find('#feedType').controlgroup('refresh');
    $(this).checkboxradio('refresh');
});
```

But neither seem to work. I also tried forcefully select (using both vanilla and jQuery methods) and un-select the buttons, but not only does this not work (?) it makes one wonder what he did with his life, I mean, this is *not* how this widget works, you don't normally have to hold its hand like this, otherwise what's the point?

#### Also worth noting

- Without the jQuery UI code, in itself, **the whole form works fine**. Events are fired, I get the values back. *Every time*.
- I have other [checkboxradio](https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/) objects elsewhere in this instance, and they work fine, every time, that is.
- In this very dialog, I have other jQuery UI objects, such as a [slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider), and they all work *fine*.

What did I do wrong that prevents this widget from working more than once?

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI installed with NPM:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1"
}
```

EDIT: Full ([module](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)) function code [here](https://pastebin.com/UnTjFYyu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I think figured it out. The dialog code was still living in the DOM after closing (either OK & cancel) and that was causing all kinds of trouble. Definitely use `'destroy'` instead of `'close'` on the dialog when it contains other JQuery UI elements :

```
$(this).dialog('destroy');
```